# Enqueue scripts not working with if is page conditional tag in functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, conditional-tags

Is this even the correct way of including scripts on a specific page?

```
function insert_mapsvg_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'mapsvg_css', site_url('/mapsvg/css/mapsvg.css') );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'nanoscroller_css', site_url('/mapsvg/css/nanoscroller.css') );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel_js', site_url('/mapsvg/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'nanoscroller_js', site_url('/mapsvg/js/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mapsvg_js', site_url('/mapsvg/js/mapsvg.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
} 

if( is_page( 37629 ) ) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_mapsvg_scripts');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the URLs are correct? You generally don't dump them in the root which is what that would be looking at...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing in the opposite way.  `Add_action` can always be active, and add the `if statement` into the function.  Like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_mapsvg_scripts');

function insert_mapsvg_scripts() {
  if( is_page( 37629 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mapsvg_css', site_url('/mapsvg/css/mapsvg.css') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nanoscroller_css', site_url('/mapsvg/css/nanoscroller.css') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel_js', site_url('/mapsvg/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nanoscroller_js', site_url('/mapsvg/js/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mapsvg_js', site_url('/mapsvg/js/mapsvg.min.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
  }
}
```

Also, as @marktruitt commented.  Generally JS is stored in the plugin or theme folder.  If it's a custom theme an enqueue may look like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/mapsvg/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

Whereas if you're using a child theme it would look like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/mapsvg/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

Comment: Additional context for OP: functions.php is too early for `is_page()` to work, because WordPress hasn't determined what kind of page is being loaded yet. You need to use it inside a function that has been hooked to a later action.